# Open image from WebView in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-webview

if webview html content has few `<img>` tags, is it possible to opens that image in fullscreen mode in new activity when user hit image in webview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. basically it is possible to invoke any kind of native Android code from within a `WebView`. You define the methods you want to expose for calling from within the `WebView` in a class, pass an instance of this class to the `WebView` and from then on the methods are invocable just like javascript methods. here comes the example (this is copy-pasted form another answer of mine; you will need to replace the video intent with image displaying intent):

**Calling native code from within web view:** 
When creating the web view add javascript interface (basically java class whose methods will be exposed to be called via javascript in the web view).

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

The definition of the javascript interface class itself (this is examplary class I took from another answer of mine and opens video in native intent)

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
        this.activity = activiy;
    }

    public void startVideo(String videoAddress){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoAddress), "video/3gpp"); // The Mime type can actually be determined from the file
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now if yo want to call this code form the html of the page you provide the following method:

```
<script>
  function playVideo(video){
    window.JSInterface.startVideo(video);
  }
</script>
```

So you need to add the appropriate method to `JSInterface` and call the code from within the Web App.